# How to use entity with using managedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I don't want to save to persistence storage. How can i use entity class without saving to persistence storage?

Comment: Please describe the issue why do you want to do this.

Comment: I want to entity class but don't want to save it in persistence store .

Comment: understood. But why?

Comment: Because don't want to save it in persistence store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the managed object context and the persistent core coordinator, you assign two persistent stores to the store coordinator:

```
NSPersistentStore *sqliteStore, *memoryStore;

sqliteStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error];
if (sqliteStore == nil) {
    // ...
}
memoryStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];
if (memoryStore == nil) {
    // ...
}
```

Later, when you insert new objects to the context, you associate the new object either with the SQLite store or the in-memory store:

```
Records *record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Records" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[context assignObject:poster toPersistentStore:memoryStore];
// or: [context assignObject:poster toPersistentStore:sqliteStore];
record.empID = ...;
record.name = ...;
```

Only the objects assigned to the SQLite store are saved to disk. Objects assigned to the in-memory store will be gone if you restart the application.

Comment: Glad that it helped.. please don't forget to upvote.. Cheers!!

Comment: -(NSPersistentStore *)inMemoryStore {
    NSError *error = nil;
     return [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];
}